# How do you move cells in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to move cells in a LibreOffice calc document. For example, suppose I have:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I want to use the mouse or keyboard to select cell 'b' and get to:

```
a
c
b
d
```

I've tried various key combinations with drag & drop, and the closest I can get to leaves the original 'b' cell behind.

The various things on https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/si/text/scalc/guide/move_dragdrop.html either don't work as described or aren't useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this - using just the keyboard, or using the mouse and the keyboard.

### "Mouseless" way

Just using the keyboard, make use of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> shortcuts to insert or remove cells respectively:

1. Select cell "b", use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy its content;
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to delete the former cell "b"; confirm with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
3. Move to cell "d";
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to insert a new cell; confirm with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to move current cell "d" down.
5. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to insert the contents from step 1.

### Mouse + Keyboard

1. **Click into cell "b", hold the left button, move the mouse to one of the adjacent cells (to the right, up or down) and back to cell "b" (still with button hold). When back on cell "b", release mouse button.** *Interim result: Background of cell "b" is highlightet, cell has a thick blue border. That's the range that LO will move in the next steps.*
2. Again, click into cell "b", **hold the left button** and **move the cursor to cell "d"** (**don't release the button yet**). *Interim Result: Cell "d" has thick black border - that's the (interim) target of the move.*
3. **Still with mouse button hold, hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and hold it.** *Interim result: thick black border of cell "d" is reduced to the border **between** cells "c" and "d". Thus, the target of the move isn't cell "d" any more but the area between "c" and "d".*
4. Release the mouse button; **then,** release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. *(Final) result: A1=a, A2=c, A3=b, A4=d, as desired.*

Here's a short clip showing the mouse/keyboard approach:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using mouse and keyboard:**

1. Select the cell you want to move content from.
2. `CTRL + Click` that same cell (it will be displayed with a fill color).
3. Press `ALT and Click` to drag it up or down.
4. Drop between the cells you want your content to be put on (it will show a thicker line).
5. Release mouse click and key.

The cells below the drop location will shift down without replacing a cell thus the range will stay the same.

[image: Dragging cell.]

Comment: Which version of LO is this on? I've just tried this on MacOS, LO 7.5.2.2, using CMD+click in step 2 and OPTION+click in step 3, and the original copy of the cell is left behind.

Comment: LibreOffice Community 7.3.7.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.